# Convert Hex to signed 64-bit with bash

Tags: bash, printf

In bash, need to convert E83E67529A1090E7 to -1711817203884453657

The following doesn't work:

```
$ printf "%d\n" "0xE83E67529A1090E7"
-bash: printf: warning: 0xE83E67529A1090E7: Numerical result out of range
9223372036854775807
```

Unsigned and positive signed values work

```
$ printf "%d\n" "0x183E67529A1090E7"
1746947309936087271
$ printf "%u\n" "0xE83E67529A1090E7"
16734926869825097959
```

but I specifically need a negative signed value which fails.

Comment: For a minute I thought that was `E83E67529A1090×64^7` because exponent notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `bash` base built-in:

```
$ echo "$((16#E83E67529A1090E7))"
-1711817203884453657
```

Comment: Don't even have to prefix it with "0x". Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` different number base's need to be wrapped with `$((num))` like:

```
$ printf "num: %d\n" $((0xffffffffffffffea))
num: -22
```

Or specify the base 16 explicitly like:

```
$ printf "num: %d\n" $((16#ffffffffffffffea))
num: -22
```